# Postgresql 9.2 where is the initdb located on Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am trying to install postgres on EC2 / EBS.
I am following [this article](http://imperialwicket.com/aws-install-postgresql-90-on-amazon-linux) and stuck at the following step.

```
sudo su -
su postgres -
/usr/pgsql-9.0/bin/initdb -D /pgdata
```

I cant find the initdb command located at the stated location, matter of fact i cant find the pgsql* directory at all under /usr folder.

Was this changed for Postgres 9.2 or is there an alternate command that would help me initdb?

*edit 1:*

I know the folder pgsql-9.0 is version specific, so i was expecting to see more like pgsql-9.2 or similar.

Comment: I strongly advise you to use the Ubuntu packages for PostgreSQL. These create a cluster for you and start the database automatically using pg_wrapper. See http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

Comment: OP doesn't really mention if he's using packages or compiling from source.  I'd hazard a guess he's already using packages and just doesn't know about the wrapper commands. Anyway, in my answer below I made the point that he should be using the various wrappers and what they're called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about EC2/EBS but your title mentions Ubuntu. The linked article mentions yum and RPM which does NOT sound like Ubuntu (or even Debian-derived).

However, in Ubuntu the stuff is below `/usr/lib/postgresql/<version>`.

Comment: yes... those instructions aren't strictly for ubuntu, you are right. And thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu you want to use the debian / postgresql wrappers that start with pg_:

pg_createcluster

is what you're looking for.  There's also

pg_lscluster
pg_dropcluster
pg_ctlcluster

just use man pages to look them up.